# Download from S3 doesn't work using RestClient

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, rest-client

I have a file which is a compressed image. Its size on disk on Windows is 125,966,232 bytes. I uploaded it to S3 using the Ruby aws-S3 gem. Its size on S3, from the properties pane, is also 125,966,232 bytes.

When I download it to disk using the web browser and the image's public URL, it downloads fine, and its size is consistent. It also uncompresses fine with my uncompression utility.

When I download the file from the S3 bucket to disk using RestClient (1.6.7), its size on disk after downloading is 126,456,885 bytes, 890,653 bytes bigger. This successful download cannot be uncompressed with my uncompression utility, and running this download repeatedly with the same S3 file gets a downloaded file, always of the size with the same file size of 126,456,885 bytes.

```
require 'rest_client'
local_file = "C:\\test\\test_download.cap"
s3_bucket = "my-bucket-not"
remote_S3_file_url = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/#{s3_bucket}/test_download.cap"
File.open(local_file, "w") do |f|
    f.write RestClient.read remote_S3_file_url
end
```

What do I have to do to ensure that the downloaded file is exactly the same size and/or decompresses properly?

Comment: Might I point out that repeatedly doing the same thing expecting a different result is a sign of madness? :-)

Comment: Often it is madness.   :)   In this case, I wanted to see if it was a consistent problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend not saving the file as text but instead as binary.

You're using:

```
File.open(local_file, "w")
```

`'w'` means:

```
"w"  Write-only, truncates existing file
     to zero length or creates a new file for writing.
```

Use the `'wb'` mode for saving the file instead. Without `'b'`, line-ends will be converted to Windows format effectively ballooning the size and corrupting the file's contents:

```
"b"  Binary file mode
     Suppresses EOL <-> CRLF conversion on Windows. And
     sets external encoding to ASCII-8BIT unless explicitly
     specified.
```

So use:

```
File.open(local_file, 'wb')
```

See "[IO Open Mode](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/IO.html#method-c-new-label-IO+Open+Mode)" for more information.

Comment: Thank you @the Tin Man. That one-character change worked perfectly, and was the missing piece to successfully orchestrate a long work flow   Thank you again!  ----- Jay